# Entity Framework 6 in Mono 3.0.10 connecting SqlServer throws a Provider Incompatible Exception

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, mono, entity-framework-6

I have created a simple console test application that works fine with Entity Framework 5 that connect a SqlServer DB.
Than, I tried to convert the project to work with Mono-3.0.10 by replacing the project reference from MS EF5 to Mono EF6, added a reference to mono EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll, 
and updated the App.Config file to Entity Framework version 6.0.0.0.
I have managed to build the project with Visual Studio 2012 under Mono 3.0.10 profile without any errors.

### Now, when I'm trying to run the project under Mono I get an exception:

### System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance ----> System.UriFormatException: Invalid Uri. The format of the Uri could not be determined: System.Data.Resources.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.ProviderManifest.xml.

Can anyone help, or at least provide a code sample showing how you do it with Mono?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing and got the same error. My solution was to compile EntityFramework from the source (Codeplex, version 6.1.0alpha) and change a line of code in SqlProviderManifest.cs

```
    private static XmlReader GetXmlResource(string resourceName)
    {
        //return XmlReader.Create(typeof(SqlProviderManifest).Assembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName), null, resourceName);
        return XmlReader.Create(typeof(SqlProviderManifest).Assembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName), null, String.Empty);
    }
```

Not nice, but solved my problem until I tried some really weird lamba query or tried to write something to the database.